# No implementation found for void com.organization.app.Activity.a() in Release

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

What I'm trying to do is simply invoke a native function from my Java android activity that is implemented in my C++ codebase. The signature can be anything, but let's define it as `void fooBar()`.

My workspace is organized in a tree structure of gradle projects, all of them "com.android.library" projects except for the app which is an "com.android.application".
All of the projects contain some form of C++ code, and a few of them contain Java classes. The activity class is in the root project ("Core"). The native implementation of the function is in a .cpp file in the same project.

This is the error output from the logcat:

```
E/com.organization.app: No implementation found for void com.organization.app.Activity.a() (tried Java_com_organization_app_Activity_a and Java_com_organization_app_Activity_a__)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
    Process: com.organization.app, PID: 3607
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.organization.app.Activity.a() (tried Java_com_organization_app_Activity_a and Java_com_organization_app_Activity_a__)
        at com.organization.app.Activity.a(Native Method)
        at com.organization.app.Activity.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
```

While building for Debug, I can invoke this `fooBar()` function faultless, but in Release it tries to load the function using a different name. Namely, `a()`. There's nothing wrong with the function signature on the native end, because if I simply change the function name to `Java_com_organization_app_Activity_a`, it is invoked successfully.
I have also tried adding more functions, and the new names for those functions became `b()` and `c()`, respectively.

It doesn't seem to matter where I invoke the function either, so the fact that it says `onStart` here is uninteresting.

I tried searching for someone with a similar problem, but all of them were problems with the function signature in C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I did some cross-referencing between Debug and Release and found out that either turning off `minifyEnabled` or removing the proguard file declaration made the exception go away. After that, I looked into the proguard file I was using (which happened to be the default one for optimization) and saw two interesting sections.

```
# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

^ This section should have made sure my native functions were not discarded from the binary. Why this happens, I still have no clue.

```
# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep
```

^ This section gave me the idea to use `@Keep` to force it to not discard the function. After some testing and making sure, it turns out this was a valid solution.

I will do some further testing to find the root cause of the shrinker not keeping my native functions, but since I found the solution I will mark this as solved. Hope this helps anyone that comes across this in the future.